# Vanity Name (Public Profile) API Permission from LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

**Does any have first hand experience applying for the basic_profile permission on LinkedIn?**
What does the process look like? who do you contact?

I am not eligible for the AdvertisingAPI (contains basic_profile) since I only need the vanity name (profile url) in order to display it in my web app. But I have read that there is a way to contact LinkedIn and apply for special permissions to their APIs.